# How to implement real time sub domain in PHP?

Tags: php, subdomain

Suppose domain is domain.name,

after a new user sign up,need to generate a new domain:user1.domain.name.

How to implement it?

BTW,is there a limit for the number of sub domains?

Answer (score 6):

I would simply use a wildcard to point all subdomains to a certain directory and have a front controller there that determines the used one from the URL - this is the easiest and safest solution from PHP.

**EDIT** Then you can obviously check whether that one should be existing (store them in a database or whatever) etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific about `determines the used one from the URL`

Comment: The domain is in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Not sure if there are any exceptions to this case, though. Then you can just explode the string by dots and off you go.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is known as Wildcard DNS record:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record

Basic DNS/Apache setup:

- http://ma.tt/2003/10/wildcard-dns-and-sub-domains/

App-side logic (crappy code):

- http://sebastiano.ezion.cc/2008/03/08/wildcard-dns-and-php/

Comment: * there is no need of domain generation and there is no limit of subdomains

Answer (score 2):

Subdomains can be retrieved with .htaccess (you need however wildcard mentioned earlier in this thread):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^user([0-9]{1,10}).domain.name$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?subdomain=%1
```